# Hibernate DAO get method does not work if called via REST, does otherwise

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, dao

I wonder if anyone can explain why the following code in a `DAO` in a `Spring` and `Hibernate` web application:

```
@Override
public Book get(Integer bookId) {
    logger.info(BookDAOImpl.class.getName() + ".get() method called.");

    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();          
    try {    
        System.out.println("Book : " + bookId);
        Book book = (Book) session.get(Book.class, bookId);    
        return book;
    }        
    finally {
        session.close();
    }                 
}
```

Will work perfectly well inside its parent web application but when called via REST through a `controller` and `service` class:

```
// Gets a Book via REST.
@RequestMapping(value="/book/{bookId}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody Object getBook(@PathVariable("bookId") String bookId) {          
    logger.info(RestController.class.getName() + ".getBook() method called.");                 
    if (bookIdValid(bookId)) {            
        Book book = bookService.get(Integer.parseInt(bookId)); 
        System.out.println("ABook " + book.toString());
        return book;             
    }
    else {             
        Messages messages = new Messages();
        messages.addMessage(messageSource.getMessage("bookId.required", null, null));                                    
        return messages;            
    }        
}
```

The line `Book book = (Book) session.get(Book.class, bookId);` returns null.

Line 53 of `BookDAOImpl` is line `return bookId == book.getBookId().intValue();` in the method below:

```
@Override
public boolean check(Integer bookId) {
    logger.info(BookDAOImpl.class.getName() + ".check() method called.");

    try {
        Book book = this.get(bookId);
        return bookId == book.getBookId().intValue();
    }
    catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

The stacktrace is:

```
    Book : 78
INFO|12 07 2015|22 07 16|http-apr-8080-exec-123|library.controller.PersonController| - library.controller.ExceptionController.exception() method called.
null
library.dao.BookDAOImpl.check(BookDAOImpl.java:53)
library.service.BookServiceImpl.check(BookServiceImpl.java:32)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:201)
com.sun.proxy.$Proxy571.check(Unknown Source)
library.controller.RestController.bookIdValid(RestController.java:127)
library.controller.RestController.getBook(RestController.java:102)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:690)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:945)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:876)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:301)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:136)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:74)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:516)
org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1015)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:652)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:277)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2451)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2440)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
library.interceptor.ClientInterceptor.afterCompletion() method completed: GET: /Library/rest/book/78?null at 12 07 2015 @ 22 07 ended with HTTP code: 500.
```

Comment: are you sure that book 78 is present? also if >= Java 8 I would have get return `Optional<Book>` and use "try-with-resources" to close instead of "finally" which could currently throw a NPE.

Comment: I doesn't return null. It throws an exception, probably a NullPointerException, at line 53 of BookDAOImpl.java. What is that line? Show us the complete relevant code of the service and the DAO. Especially how the fields are declared and initialized.

Comment: This is a `Java 1.7` project. The `bookId` parameter to the get method is populated and the `check` method, which calls the `get` in some cases is appended to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `session.get(Book.class, bookId)` is returning null - your database likely does not contain book 78. Do you have a create book endpoint you can use to insert into the database prior to hitting the get endpoint?

Comment: True. `Book` 78 does not exist and if I try this method with a valid `Book`, everything is fine. But, and this is why I posted this issue, an identical piece of code, but for another class, works perfectly well without producing any stack trace. If the `Book` doesn't exist, the method should simply return a message saying so. But I get the stack trace instead.

Comment: Inside `check()` catch `Exception` instead of `IndexOutOfBoundsException`?

Comment: In the end I just added `NullPointerException` to be `catch` block in the `check` method. This is only a demo application so I'm not too concerned about rough edges, so to speak.